# Not able to change Edittext value inside listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

Hello Friends below is my code

**Main.Java**

```
public class NewMain extends Activity {

ListView mListView;
DatabaseConnectionAPI mDatabaseConnectionAPI;
ArrayList<ParserCategory> mArrayList;
InteractiveListViewAdapter mInteractiveListViewAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDatabaseConnectionAPI = new DatabaseConnectionAPI(
            getApplicationContext());
    try {
        mDatabaseConnectionAPI.createDataBase();
        mDatabaseConnectionAPI.openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mArrayList = new ArrayList<ParserCategory>();
    mArrayList = mDatabaseConnectionAPI.getCategoryData();

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyList);
    mInteractiveListViewAdapter=new InteractiveListViewAdapter(NewMain.this,R.layout.item,mArrayList);
    mListView.setAdapter(mInteractiveListViewAdapter);

}

public class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected EditText scores;
}

public class InteractiveListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParserCategory>

{
    ArrayList<ParserCategory>mList;
    Activity context;

    public InteractiveListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<ParserCategory> mArrayList) {
        super(context, R.layout.item,mArrayList);
        this.context=(Activity) context;
        mList=mArrayList;
    }

    @Override   
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {        
        View view = null;  
        if (convertView == null)
        {             
            LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater(); 

            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.item, null); 

            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(); 
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);   
            viewHolder.scores=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ItemCaption);    
            viewHolder.scores.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
            {  
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {      
                    ParserCategory element=(ParserCategory)viewHolder.scores.getTag();            
                    element.setCdesc(s.toString());        
                }        
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after)
                {       
                }      
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                {                              
                }
            });         
            viewHolder.scores.setTag(mList.get(position));
            view.setTag(viewHolder);   
        } 
        else 
        {
            view = convertView; 
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).scores.setTag(mList.get(position)); 
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();    
        holder.text.setText(mList.get(position).getCname());    
        holder.scores.setText(mList.get(position).getCdesc());   
        return view;

    }
 }

 }
```

**My activity_main.xml file as below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/MyList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fadingEdge="none" >
   </ListView>

  </LinearLayout>
```

**My item.xml file as below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="dfd" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ItemCaption"
    android:editable="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
  >
</EditText>
```

When I run the above code I am not able to change `EditText` value in `ListView`. The issue is that when I focus on any `EditText` in listitem I am not able to write text on `EditText`, so any idea how can I solve it?

Comment: where is your listener for listview.?

Comment: use `onTextChangeListener` after `else` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the issue.

I just make a single line change in my code in `getview` method, I just add one line

```
viewHolder.scores.setId(position);
```

because in `onTextchangelistner` I am accessing position with `getId` but in `getview` I haven't `setid` with `setId(position)` so that's why in `ListView` particular `EditText` item id is not set and I am not able to change text.

So I have just make a change by adding the above line and it works fine for me.

Comment: please tell me what to write in position